# Population datatable and assigning to report

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

i am picking set of complaintcodes from table and saving all in datatable, now i want to populate another datatable via store procedure by passing Complaintcode from previous datatable, one by one, and it should load 1 by 1 record in datatable, and finally assigning it to report.

i have tried but in foreach loop it only shows me last records not all. I want all records.

```
DateTime fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtFromDate.Text, "dd/MMM/yyyy", null);
DateTime toDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtToDate.Text, "dd/MMM/yyyy", null);
DataTable dt_temp = MyComplaints.SearchAllComplaintByDate(fromDate, toDate);

ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Report_Complaints24Hours_Sdpo.rdlc");

foreach(DataRow row in dt_temp.Rows)
{
    string ComplaintCode = Convert.ToString(row["ComplaintCode"]);
    DataTable dt = ManageRecievedMessage.Report_Complaints24Hours_Sdpo(ComplaintCode);
}
```

Comment: Isn't that normal? Every time you iterate, you re-report your values to `dt` reference. And at the end, you have the last value of `row` and you report this to `dt`.

Comment: i can't find any solution please help me, i have spent almost a day on it